# Google Apps Free to Business and Change primary domain

Tags: google-workspace

I have a Google Apps Free with 2 domain:

- A is primary domain (3 users with many many mail, docs, calendars, etc...)
- B another domain (0 users)

A company made ​​me a very attractive confirmed offer to sell my A domain.
Can i remove this domain (A) and use only B domain without losing free account?
Or i need to upgrade to Business?

Please let me know - it's very important and urgent.
I need take a decision!

Answer (score 1):

> Can i remove this domain (A) and use only B domain without losing free account

No, that's not possible. Each Google Apps for domain is a separate Google account, and unless you'd created the Google account when the free tier was running, you cannot transfer the free account status across domains